# Typescript compiler "cannot find module" when using Webpack require for CSS/image assets

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am writing **vanilla Javascript** but using the Typescript compiler's `checkJs` option to do type checking in VSCode.  I have Webpack set up to load various asset types (CSS, images, etc), which works fine for builds, but Code is treating these statements as an error.  For example, in this code

```
require("bootstrap");
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");
var img = require("../img/image.png");
```

the first line is fine but the next two both show an error under the (string) argument to `require()`, with the tooltip "Cannot find module (name)".

I have installed `@types/webpack` and `@types/webpack-env`, which fixed `resolve()` and `resolve.context()`.  Am I missing another typings package or is this an issue I need to take up on [the DT issue tracker](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/)?

Comment: You can get this to work but you will have to create a type declaration file. There is no way to express the asset synthetic modules using vanilla JS.

Comment: Would you maybe have a link illustrating how to do this?  I don't know much Typescript, I'm just trying to take advantage of the type checking but I don't want to litter my code with `//@ts-ignore` so I'm trying to fix it "correctly"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Requiring non JS or TS resources is currently not supported by the TypeScript server which powers VS Code's JavaScript and TypeScript intellisense. Here's the issue tracking this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15146

As a workaround, try creating a `d.ts` file in your project with the content:

```
declare module '*.css' { export default '' as string; }
declare module '*.png' { export default '' as string; }
```

You can also suppress individual errors by adding `// @ts-ignore` before the require:

```
// @ts-ignore
var img = require("../img/image.png");
```

Comment: I had the `@ts-ignore`s all over the place but it'd be nice to have a more consistent default behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon -- I'm now seeing `[js] Type 'typeof '*.svg'' is not assignable to type 'string'.`.  But I'm exporting "as string" -- what gives?  (Your example does get rid of the errors for the `require("path/to/whatever.css")`, since the return value is never assigned to anything.)

Comment: Now, this is fascinating.  I added a number of `declare module` lines to my `globals.d.ts`, as you suggested.  Assigning `require("path/to/my.svg")` to a `string`-typed var gives the "is not assignable" error, but `import mySvg from "path/to/my.svg"; aStringVar = mySvg;` works great.  Maybe I found a bug in `require()`?  For now, I'm changing all my requires to imports, since Webpack apparently handles them both just fine.

Comment: TS compiler tells me export must be an identifier. I used `const val: string; export default val` instead.