# Import directory of SVGs as array with VueJS

Tags: webpack, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'd like to import a directory full of SVG assets, and reference those as an array within my VueJS component. Something like the following:

```
//LevelComponent.vue

<template>
  <div v-html="image"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as levels from '@/assets/levels/*.svg'

export default {
  name: "Level",
  data() {
    return {
      image: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setLevel(levelNumber) {
      this.level = levels[levelNumber];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The above obviously doesn't work because of how VueJS/Webpack handles asset paths:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/levels/*.svg'
```

We currently load the SVGs separately, but this requires a update in our code every time the contents of the directory changes:

```
import level1 from '@/assets/levels/1.svg'
import level2 from '@/assets/levels/2.svg'
import level3 from '@/assets/levels/3.svg'
```

Other than the above error, I'm pretty sure I'm going about this the wrong way. What would the correct way be to approach this? I should mention we currently use `svg-inline-loader` in Webpack to load the individual SVGs.

Comment: Maybe will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568377/imports-not-recognizing-image-modules-in-react-using-webpack-with-typescript/49568518#49568518

Comment: Are the filenames of the svgs known ahead of time?

Comment: @Scott Ideally, no. It would be great for it to simply autoload all files in the folder. A colleague today suggested that we generate the JS to load the files outside of Vue, and then insert it at a placeholder in the Vue component before it compiles. I might just go down that route if I don't find something nicer.

Comment: @ConstantMeiring webpack handles dynamic assets differently, in my project whenever I'm importing something like `*.svg` I must use the relative path to the assets folder:

`import * as levels from '../assets/levels/*.svg'`

Comment: If you're importing them in order to speed up load times (caching) then that's one thing, but if your importing them just to use in a `v-for` then there are other solutions I can suggest, esp if you have predictable file-names.

Comment: They get imported for both caching and use within templates (without knowing filenames beforehand), so it's a bit tricky.